# Photos captured from Android camera are completely black

Tags: android, camera, image

I make a camera and try to capture a picture. Since the original data is YUV, I turn it into RGB using function:

```
static public void decodeYUV420SP(byte[] rgbBuf, byte[] yuv420sp,int width, int height)
```

However, the photo saved is completely black, there is no content in it.

I also found the following way:

```
mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
```

but the project was shut down.

Are there any other effective ways to save a photo? Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

An old post, but it speaks of a similar problem that I have so I might as well answer the part I know :)

You're probably doing it wrong. I suggest you use the JPEG callback to store the image:

```
mCamera.takePicture(null, null, callbackJPEG);
```

This way you will get JPEG data into the routine which you can store into a file unmodified:

```
final Camera.PictureCallback mCall = new Camera.PictureCallback()
{
  @Override
  public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)
  {
    //Needs <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File file = new File(sdCard, "pic.jpg");
    fil = new FileOutputStream(file);
    fil.write(data);
    fil.close();          
  }
}
```

As far as the black picture goes, I have found that placing a simple `Thread.sleep(250)` between `camera.startPreview()` and `camera.takePicture()` takes care of that particular problem on my Galaxy Nexus.
I have no idea why this delay is necessary. Even if I add `camera.setOneShotPreviewCallback()` and call `camera.takePicture()` from the callback, the image comes out black if I don't first delay...
Oh, and the delay is not just "some" delay. It has to be some pretty long value. For example, `250ms` sometimes works, sometimes not on my phone.

Comment: Now I'm struggling with the same issue. And my device is Galaxy Nexus as well. Did you manage to find a working solution?

Comment: Did you get completely black photos on other devices?

Comment: Working solution described in the answer. Yes, the issue was confirmed by users of other devices.

Comment: I do not have that information. A few. Then I increased the delay and reports stopped coming in. Note that delay was there from the start since my own device refused to work without it.

Answer (score 2):

The complete black photo is a result of immediate call to `mCamera.takePicture()` after calling `mCamera.startPreview()`. Android should be given appropriate time to process its autofocus activity before taking the actual picture. The blackness is result of erratic exposure caused due to interruption while the autofocus was happening.

I recommend calling `mCamera.autoFocus()` right after `mCamera.startPreview()`.

The `mCamera.takePicture()` should be called in the callback function of the autofocus function call.

This flow ensures that the picture is taken after the autofocus is complete and removes blackness or exposure issues from the image taken.

The delay mentioned in **Velis'** answer works for some devices because those devices complete autofocus activity. Ensuring proper callback flow removes this arbitrary delay and would work on every device.

Comment: Thank you! I'm building a massive database of images and a few percent of them are simply black.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue using following argument:

```
final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
```

When I was using TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE instead of TEMPLATE_PREVIEW, which was capturing my image as full black image. This thing works in my case.

Comment: I did this plus use CONTINUOUS_PICTURE and setRepeating (...)