# Images from camera 2 api save as black images -Android Camera 2 api

Tags: android, image, android-camera

I am developing a custome camera but when trying to capture an image using `Camera 2 api`then i am getting black image.i am using below code for capture

> 

```
CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            String cameraId = "";
            if (cameraFront) {
                cameraId = "" + findFrontFacingCamera();
            } else {
                cameraId = "" + findBackFacingCamera();
            }

            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
            // CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(mCameraDevice.getId());

            Size[] jpegSizes = null;
            if (characteristics != null) {
                jpegSizes =
                        characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP).getOutputSizes(
                                ImageFormat.JPEG);
            }
            int width = 720;
            int height = 640;
            if (jpegSizes != null && 0 < jpegSizes.length) {
                width = jpegSizes[0].getWidth();
                height = jpegSizes[0].getHeight();
            }
            StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
            Size largest =
                    Collections.max(Arrays.asList(map.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG)), new CompareSizesByArea());
            ImageReader reader =
                    ImageReader.newInstance(largest.getWidth(), largest.getHeight(), ImageFormat.JPEG, /* maxImages */1);
            // ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
            List<Surface> outputSurfaces = new ArrayList<Surface>(2);
            outputSurfaces.add(reader.getSurface());
            outputSurfaces.add(new Surface(mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture()));

            final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder =
                    mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            captureBuilder.addTarget(reader.getSurface());
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);

            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_ALWAYS_FLASH);

            // Orientation
            int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            if (cameraFront) {
                captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation) + 180);

            } else {
                captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
            }
            final File file = getOutputMediaFile();

            ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readerListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader)
                {

                    Image image = null;
                    try {
                        image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                        // ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                        // final byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];

                        ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                        final byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];

                        buffer.get(bytes);
                        save(bytes);
                        buffer.clear();
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                        {

                            @Override
                            public void run()
                            {
                                mThumbnail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                filePathLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                filePathValue.setText(file.getAbsolutePath());

                                Bitmap bmp =
                                        UtilityMethods.getScaledBitmap(CameraImageTestActivityLoliipop.this, bytes);
                                mThumbnail.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                            }
                        });

                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        AppLogger.exception(myContext, getClass().getSimpleName(), e);
                        // e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        AppLogger.exception(myContext, getClass().getSimpleName(), e);
                        // e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        if (image != null) {
                            image.close();
                        }
                    }
                }

                private void save(byte[] bytes) throws IOException
                {
                    OutputStream output = null;
                    try {
                        output = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        output.write(bytes);

                    } finally {
                        if (null != output) {
                            output.close();
                        }
                    }
                }

            };

            HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("CameraPicture");
            thread.start();
            final Handler backgroudHandler = new Handler(thread.getLooper());
            reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(readerListener, backgroudHandler);

            final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureListener = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback()
            {

                @Override
                public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request,
                                               TotalCaptureResult result)
                {

                    super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);

                    startPreview();
                }

            };

            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(outputSurfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback()
            {

                @Override
                public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session)
                {

                    try {
                        session.capture(captureBuilder.build(), captureListener, backgroudHandler);
                    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                        AppLogger.exception(myContext, getClass().getSimpleName(), e);
                        // e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session)
                {

                }
            }, backgroudHandler);

        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            AppLogger.exception(myContext, getClass().getSimpleName(), e);
            // e.printStackTrace();
        }


and below are the methods for camera preview
```

> protected void startPreview()
>           {
>               try {

```
            if (null == mCameraDevice || !mTextureView.isAvailable() || null == mPreviewSize) {
                Log.e(TAG, "startPreview fail, return");
                return;
            }

            SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
            if (null == texture) {
                Log.e(TAG, "texture is null, return");
                return;
            }
            Log.e(TAG, "Width: " + mPreviewSize.getWidth() + "  Hieght : " + mPreviewSize.getHeight());
            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
            Surface surface = new Surface(texture);

            try {
                mPreviewBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
                mPreviewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_ALWAYS_FLASH);

            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                AppLogger.exception(myContext, getClass().getSimpleName(), e);
                // e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mPreviewBuilder.addTarget(surface);

            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback()
            {

                @Override
                public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session)
                {

                    mPreviewSession = session;
                    updatePreview();
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session)
                {

                }
            }, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            AppLogger.exception(myContext, getClass().getSimpleName(), e);
            // e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected void updatePreview()
    {
        try {
            if (null == mCameraDevice) {
                Log.e(TAG, "updatePreview error, return");
            }

            mPreviewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
            // mPreviewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
            // Flash is automatically enabled when necessary.
            mPreviewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_ALWAYS_FLASH);

            HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("CameraPreview");
            thread.start();
            Handler backgroundHandler = new Handler(thread.getLooper());

            mPreviewSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewBuilder.build(), null, backgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
          }
```

its working in all devices but when i am runnig on `Micromax Q382` device then getting black image with below warning in logcat

> I/Choreographer: Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   W/ImageReader_JNI: Unable to acquire a lockedBuffer, very likely client tries to lock more than maxImages buffers

I am not getting any idea that what happening.Please Help me.

Comment: Please try with a small delay between camera preview and camera capture..Also did you tried taking a picture on the issue device with default camera.Is its camera working properly ?

Comment: Thanks for reply @Sunil
Yes I have checked its working with default camera.and also its running in all devices but when trying to run in micromax Q382 device then its capturing black Image

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417608/photos-captured-from-android-camera-are-completely-black

Comment: I have tried with delay but its not working.And i am using Camera 2 api

Comment: Sry I am not familiar with camera 2..

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a `null` argument to `createCaptureSession` inside `startPreview`. Make `backgroudHandler` previously used visible to that method (pass as parameter or initialize it as a class variable) and use there as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting some delay before starting the capture (and after opening the camera). Something like:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
     //takePicture();
}, 500);
```

If you want, I've created a service that massively facilitates photos capturing with Android Camera 2 API: https://github.com/hzitoun/android-camera2-secret-picture-taker . Usage is described in the readme file.

Hope that helped!

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the AE mode to 'always flash', but then you don't run the precapture sequence to allow the camera device to meter for that flash; this will likely not work very well on any device, and on some devices you may end up with some default exposure value (bad).

If you want to fire the flash, you need to use a precapture sequence first (send a single request with AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER set, wait for the PRECAPTURE AE_STATE to end, then issue the capture request), on non-LEGACY devices.  If the device is LEGACY-level, then your current code should be OK for those.